# Error in LSTM embedding layer's shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm

I have this network architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(9761, 100, input_length=longest_period))
model.add(LSTM(30, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I try to fit the model:

```
res = model.fit(X_train_lsmt, np.array(y_train_lsmt), validation_split=0.25, epochs=2, batch_size=128, verbose=0)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected
embedding_3_input to have shape (None, 217) but got array 
with shape (3133, 1)
```

I suppose that the error could be about the one-hot encoded `y_train_lsmt`, having shape `(3133,3)`

`[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]`

but I am not sure about this.

**Update:**

I have partially solved adding a `Flatten()` layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(9761, 100, input_length=stringa_piu_lunga))
model.add(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but now I get the same error during model evaluation:

`score = model.evaluate(X_test_lsmt, y_train_lsmt, verbose=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Change your `y_train_lstm` to categorical with:

```
y_train_lstm = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train_lstm)
```

Or change your loss to sparse_categorical_entropy:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

---

**Edited**: Based on your github repository, the evaluation not going to work because you did not preprocess the `x_test_lstm`. Try:

```
X_test_lstm = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test_lstm, maxlen=longest_string)
```

Comment: I have tried both your suggested changes, I but I get the same error.

Comment: Would it possible to put all of your code? It is some part of your code and it's almost fine. Look at the example here: https://github.com/hadifar/tensorflow-starter/blob/master/lesson3/imdb_rnn_keras.py

Comment: This is the link to the main part of my code: https://github.com/SimoCanc/LSTM/blob/master/LSTM.py